# Highcharts setExtremes animation causes graphical issues

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to use highcharts for my current project. Everything works fine except for the animation when the chart is redrawn. Basically I am just using this code:

```
chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
chart.series[0].setData(data1, false);
chart.series[1].setData(data2, false);
chart.get('navigator').setData(data3, false);
chart.redraw();
chart.hideLoading();
```

On this [gif](http://gifyu.com/image/BZZ) you can see that there are some weird artifacts in the chart when it gets redrawn and the animation gets triggered. Anyone has an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: I could create a fiddle for this issue. Check this out.
http://jsfiddle.net/njsz2tb8/1/
Click on '1w' first, then on '1d'.

Comment: I don't you really need your redraw right here. You are using setExtremes, not afterSetExtremes so you are redrawing twice (which is the reason of weird animation). Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/njsz2tb8/3/ If it will meet your requirements, I will post it as an answer

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that setExtremes calls chart.redraw(). But unfortunately this isn't working for my case because I use async ajax requests to set the new data. So setExtremes is already finished when the callback of my ajax function is reached. I tried to simulate the ajax functionality with timeouts in this fiddle. You can see that for example the tooltips aren't working if I don't redraw my chart by myself. http://jsfiddle.net/njsz2tb8/4/

Comment: So maybe use afterSetExtremes method instead of setExtremes?http://jsfiddle.net/njsz2tb8/5/

Comment: I think afterSetExtremes also ignores async callbacks. If you start your fiddle you can see the graphical issues again by clicking on '1w'.

Comment: Hm, it is really interesting issue. As a workaround, I think you can add more timeout for your chart redraw: http://jsfiddle.net/njsz2tb8/6/

Comment: Well, I think I will just use setData() with the last parameter set to true. This will redraw the graph everytime I use setData. Maybe it is a bit slower to redraw the graph twice and the animation is also gone but at least there are no graphical issues then.